# How to handle a request with HTTPS protocol in Roku SG while website insecure?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working on a Roku Scene Graph application. It gets request data from remote servers specified by URLs. However, the response was not returning and showing an error:

> SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name...

How do I make a request with an HTTPS URL while the website is insecure?

My code for request data is below:

```
request = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")  
request.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
request.AddHeader("X-Roku-Reserved-Dev-Id", "")
request.InitClientCertificates()
request.SetUrl(url)  
port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
request.SetMessagePort(port)
request.SetPort(port)    
timer = createobject("roTimeSpan")
request.AsyncGetToString()   
while true    
    msg = wait(10, port)
    if type(msg) = "roUrlEvent" then
        if msg.GetResponseCode() = 200 then
            m.data = msg.GetString()   
            return m.data
            exit while
        else
            print msg.GetResponseCode() 
            print msg.GetFailureReason()
            exit while
        end if        
    end if      
end while
```

Code for download images:-

```
mgr = CreateObject("roTextureManager")
msgport = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
mgr.SetMessagePort(msgport)

request = CreateObject("roTextureRequest","https://192.168.1.10/ball.png")
request.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
request.InitClientCertificates()

mgr.RequestTexture(request)
```

Comment: Did you configure web server for ssl mutual authentication?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is the certificate issue should be fixed on the server side.

Back to your question, you can disable SSL verification on Roku by using [the method `EnableHostVerification(enable as Boolean) as Boolean` of the `ifUrlTransfer` interface](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifUrlTransfer#ifUrlTransfer-EnableHostVerification(enableasBoolean)asBoolean).

```
request.EnableHostVerification(false)
```